# How to use command-line to cause Qsys to generate only synthesis or only simulation files?

Tags: intel-fpga, quartus

In my project there are several Qsys files. Some of them are for synthesis but most are for testbench. When changes are made to source code, I usually just run generate Qsys system from the GUI and select the appropriate option for generating only synthesis or only simulation files. However, this is clearly a tedious process. Here exists a potential for improvement.

I want to write a Python script which shall look for Qsys files, and when found, it shall check if it has a tb_ prefix or _tb suffix. If such a string exists, it shall run Qsys generate to only generate simulation files with VHDL option. Otherwise, it shall run Qsys generate to only generate synthesis files with VHDL option.

I know how to do the Python part. I can use the subprocess built in Python package. I am not sure how to do the Qsys generate part in command-line. How do I do the above using Qsys through command-line?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the log files that Quartus and qsys write out. There should be a log file or journal file that may contain some of the relevant commands. I'm not sure about qsys proper, but you can definitely automate the generation of qsys IP from the command line. See https://github.com/alexforencich/verilog-ethernet/tree/master/example/S10DX_DK/fpga_10g for an example that uses makefiles to do this.